# How to raise seperate events instances of a user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

I have a user control that raises an event when a file is uploaded to it's internal FileUpload control. When there's only one instance of the user control registered the event to the page, it works fine. When I add a second instance, the first event no longer works. If I trigger the event from the first or second instance, they both end up running the UserControl2_FileSelected method. I would like to have a separate method run for each user control on the page.

Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyUserControls.Default" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Classes/Controls/FileUploader.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="FileUploader" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <uc1:FileUploader runat="server" id="FileUploader1" Text="Uploader 1" />
    <uc1:FileUploader runat="server" ID="FileUploader2" Text="Uploader 2" />
</asp:Content>
```

Page code behind:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileUploader1.FileSelected += new EventHandler(UserControl1_FileSelected);
            FileUploader2.FileSelected += new EventHandler(UserControl2_FileSelected);
        }

        protected void UserControl1_FileSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //handle event from instance 1
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Control 1");
        }

        protected void UserControl2_FileSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //handle event from instance 2
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Control 2");
}
}
```

User Control code behind:

```
public partial class FileUploader : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public event EventHandler FileSelected;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (this.FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    this.FileSelected(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Delegate`, not `EventHandler`

In the User Control

```
private Delegate _FileSelected;
public Delegate FileSelected
{
    set { _FileSelected = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            //invoke the command in the parent
            _FileSelected.DynamicInvoke(FileUpload1.FileName);
        }
    }
```

And then on the page containing the Controls

```
delegate void FileSelected(string value);

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add the delegates to the usercontrol
    FileSelected fileSelected1 = new FileSelected(UserControl1_FileSelected);
    FileUploader1.FileSelected = fileSelected1;

    FileSelected fileSelected2 = new FileSelected(UserControl2_FileSelected);
    FileUploader2.FileSelected = fileSelected2;
}

private void UserControl1_FileSelected(string value)
{
    Label1.Text += "1: " + value + "<br>";
}

private void UserControl2_FileSelected(string value)
{
    Label1.Text += "2: " + value + "<br>";
}
```